# Select box value to href

Tags: javascript, html, select, href

I'm add multilingual functionality to my page and having trouble with a select box. I want to change the language dynamically displayed on a page to match the chosen language in the select box.

This is my html code:

```
<?php
include_once 'multilingual_common.php';
?>

<!DOCTYPE>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Test Form</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="languages">
        <select onChange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
            <option value="multilingual_test.html?lang=en">English</option>
            <option value="multilingual_test.html?lang=ko">한국어</option>
        </select>
        <a href="multilingual_test.html?lang=en">English</a>
        <a href="multilingual_test.html?lang=ko">한국어</a>
    </div>
    <ul>
        <li><?php echo $lang['CHARACTER_NAME']; ?> Rose</li>
        <li><?php echo $lang['CHARACTER_LEVEL']; ?> 40</li>
        <li><?php echo $lang['CHARACTER_SEX']; ?> female</li>
        <li><?php echo $lang['CHARACTER_SEX']; ?> none</li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

It works when clicking the  tag but not the select box. The onChange event used in  tag doesn't work. How should I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using a select list. Getting the value is a tad more complex.
A select list has many `options`. The options are an array under the `this` object in the `onchange` event.

The current selected index is stored in `this.selectedIndex`

So to get a value, you need to acces the correct option in the array by the selected value

```
this.options[this.selectedIndex].value
```

is how you get a value from a select list.

To fix your code you should use instead of

```
<select onChange="if (this.value) window.location.href=this.value">
```

you need to get the value of the option

```
<select onChange="if (this.options[this.selectedIndex].value) window.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value">
```

Comment: The href of first option doesn't work but second option is navigated well though. The first option is fixed and It isn't changed when i click the second option.

Comment: add a blank option as the first option. `<option value="">- Select a language -</option>`

Comment: Ah it works properly. Thank you so much for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<select  onchange="location = this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;">
            <option value="multilingual_test.html?lang=en">English</option>
            <option value="multilingual_test.html?lang=ko">한국어</option>
        </select>
```